# Is it possible to make a window in Java using swing that has a border but not a title bar?

Tags: java, swing

This is the result I'm after:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LeCwF.png]

If it's not possible, that's all I need to hear. If it is possible, I would appreciate an explanation of how to make it happen. I am going to have a menu bar so people can close the window with that.

Comment: in the future, please attempt something 1st , to show efforts .  We like to see attempt at coding it, this way we feel like u r learnin

Comment: Not one that uses the native look and feel window border

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use an undecorated `JFrame`. Then you just add a `Border` to the `JRootPane` of the frame:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame(...);
frame.setUndecorated( true );
frame.getRootPane().setBorder( new MatteBorder(4, 4, 4, 4, Color.BLUE) );
```

Comment: @mKorbel, same to you... :)